# How to sync and backup image to/from cloud?

Tags: android, synchronization, cloud

I want to develop one application which is useful to sync data on cloud.
I have some information about the C2DM but C2DM service send little message from server
to client mobile for update but I need to send data from client mobile to
server.

Using this application the user can sync data on cloud and if user loses his mobile, then the user will be able to restore it from cloud to mobile.

Please provide me some hint or code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C2DM won't do what you need. You'll need a server solution, perhaps Google App Engine, Amazon S3 storage, or your own server.

It's possible you can use Android data backup, but I suspect your data is too large

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html